# Use the operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}$ to thow that $f(z)=2ix$ is not an holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

How could I use the operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}$ to thow that $f(z)=2ix$ is not an holomorphic function?

I don't know how to proceed. Is anyone could help me at this point?

Answer (score 1):

A function is holomorphic on an open set $U$ if $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}f(x,y) = 0$ for all $(x,y)\in U$. Noting that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$, do you see how to proceed?

The condition $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} f= 0$ is equivalent to the Cauchy-Riemann equations but is conceptually a bit nicer since it immediately shows that $f$ is independent of $\bar z$.

Comment: Do I have to use $x=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$?

Comment: yes, equivalently that $z = x+iy$, that's what the exercice supposed

Comment: @RobertDavis You can, but you do not have to. That is why I wrote the alternate formulation of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}$ down. Of course those two relationships are **extremely** closely related.

Comment: So as it is not holomorphic, it is sufficient to show that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}f(x,y) \not= 0$, right?

Comment: @RobertDavis You need to show that it is (edit) **not** holomorphic and one such way to do that is to show that the partial with respect to $\overline{z}$ is not zero. (I'm not sure if that's what you meant.)

Comment: Are you certain it is holomorphic, because the exercise ask that the function is not holomorphic?

Comment: My bad. I forgot to put the word "not" in there!